# Add a Component to two different JTabbedPanes

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a `LinkedList` of `Components`, each of which I would like to add into two different `JTabbedPanes`. For some reason, Swing is only letting me put each component into one or the other. The code I'm using is the following:

```
/* The two tab panes */
JTabbedPane leftTabs = new JTabbedPane();
JTabbedPane rightTabs = new JTabbedPane();

for (int i=0; i<tabPanes.size(); i++) {
    rightTabs.add(tabPanes.get(i));
    leftTabs.add(tabPanes.get(i));
}
```

Whichever `add` call I put last is the one that works; if I add to `leftTabs` last, then `rightTabs` ends up empty, and vice-versa.

Any ideas on how to get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A component can only have a single parent, so you can't add it to two different tabs.

However the model of the component can be shared. For example:

```
JTextField textField1 = new JTextField();
JTextField textField2 = new JTextField();
textField2.setDocument( textField1.getDocument() );
```

So somehow you to figure out how to share models, not the components.